# How to dynamically create Scl variables in sas scl

Tags: sas, sas-af

I'm searching for a solution to a problem several programmers struggle with but I can't find any solution on the Internet. Here it is:

Starting with a SAS table containing name/value pairs. Example:

```
varName          varValue 
Name             Bart
Age              54
Job              writer
Start            1983
```

The Scl program should read the contents of the table and make a Scl variable for each varName/varValue pair.

It should be easy to do something trivial like that but I just can't find the right way. It's driving me nuts. Does someone have a solution?

Bart

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of putting 2 variables from a data set into a scl list which is a very good container for data when using scl rather than unknown number of individual variables. It doesn't matter how many rows in table and you can then use list functions to access data by name. 
Save this code to a catalog entry sasuser.mymethods.Copytwovar2list.scl
The INIT:  has a test example of it you could have a separate scl  entry with that usage.

```
COPY_TWO_VAR_VALUES_TO_LIST:
   *-----------------------------------------------------------------*
   | Method Name: COPY_TWO_VAR_VALUES_TO_LIST
   *--------------------------Entry Parameters-----------------------*
   | d_id      8   I   Input dataset id
   | l_id      8   O   output list
   | var1     $32  I   Var1 - Name of list item
   | var2     $32  I   Var2 - Value of item
   *-----------------------------------------------------------------*;
   method dsname     $45
          l_id        8
          var1       $32
          var2       $32
           ;
   d_id=open(dsname,'i');

   varnum1=varnum(d_id,var1);
   vartyp1=vartype(d_id,varnum1);

   if var1 ne var2 then do;
       varnum2=varnum(d_id,var2);
       vartyp2=vartype(d_id,varnum2);
   end;

   * --- fill the list with data set values;
   do while(fetch(d_id) ne -1 );
      i+1;
      if vartyp1='C' then
         u_vname=getvarc(d_id,varnum1);
      else
         u_vname=left(putn(getvarn(d_id,varnum1),'BEST12.'));

      if var1 ne var2 then do;
          if vartyp2='C' then
             u_vvalue=getvarc(d_id,varnum2);
          else
             u_vvalue=left(putn(getvarn(d_id,varnum2),'BEST12.'));

      end;
      else
         u_vvalue = u_vname;
      rc=setitemc(l_id,u_vvalue,i,'Y');
      u_vname=nameitem(l_id,i,u_vname);
   end;
   rc=close(d_id);
endmethod;

INIT:
* --- test example of usage ;
l_list=makelist();

call method('sasuser.mymethods.copytwovar2list.scl', 
    'COPY_TWO_VAR_VALUES_TO_LIST',
    'sashelp.class',l_list,
    'NAME',
    'AGE');

call putlist(l_list,'l_list=',2);

return;
```